# How to undo php artisan storage:link command that deleting all storage folder content

Tags: php, laravel

I uploaded an image file using this code.

```
// Get filename with the extension
$filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
// Get just filename
$filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
// Get just ext
$extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
// Filename to store
$fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
// Upload Image
$path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
```

Then tried to make a symlink to the storage folder so it can be accessible from the public folder. I typed this command `php artisan storage:link` in the `cmd`, But then it destroyed all the contents in the storage folder and deleted it then displayed this error.

> ```
> The system cannot find the path specified.
> The [public/storage] directory has been linked.
> ```

[image]

Now when I run the server `PHP artisan serve` I get this error.

[image: Browser error]

I am new to laravel and now am stuck, how can I solve this? The storage folder was recreated with nothing but log files in it.

[image: storage folder empty]

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this error. The good thing is that I had a copy of the same project in another directory, so I delete the current storage folder showing log files only and the copy and pasted the storage folder from the other project I had backedup and re-uploaded the image. After that, I used the same command `php artisan storage:link` but this time I had the public folder path selected

[`C:\xampp\htdocs\mwalimu_shaaban\public`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIlk5.png)

[`C:\xampp\htdocs\mwalimu_shaaban>php artisan storage:link
The [public/storage] directory has been linked.`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecHtM.png)

I Think the problem arouse since I had not selected the symbolic link destination path in the beginning.

Comment: But I still can't figure it out if I didn't have a backup. Anyone with an idea?